# How to solve "Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect." in c#

Tags: c#

How to solve

> "Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in
>   the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or
>   password is incorrect."

when I am creating/moving file to network path I got the above error. And below I have mentioned my Web config tag.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="UserName" password="******"/>
```

Comment: Without some code and the config this question will be put "on hold" really fast...

Comment: Have you checked, if Windows is right ? Perhaps a typeo in userName or password. If running in a domain then it the domain should be included in the userName.

Comment: The password in the config file is wrong. Resolve this by putting the correct password in. Possibly your issue is to do with ASPNET_SETREG though: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/329290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious reason is that `userName` or `password` is wrong in your `Web.config` file.

Another possible reason is that the userName has no domain information.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN\UserName" password="******"/>
```